# Importing obj file from 3DS Max to Phaser3

Tags: phaser-framework, 3dsmax

In my Phaser3 game, I am trying to import a 3D model from an .obj file to be the main character of my game.
My code is :

```
class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super("startScene");
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.image("texture", "assets/images/<filename>.png");
    this.load.obj({
      key: "keymodel",
      url: "assets/models/<filename>.obj",
      matURL: "assets/models/<filename>.mtl",
    });
  }
  create(){
    const mesh = this.add.mesh(50,50,"texture");
    mesh.addVerticesFromObj('keymodel', 0.1);
    mesh.panZ(7);
    mesh.modelRotation.y += 0.5;

    this.debug = this.add.graphics();
    mesh.setDebug();

    console.log(mesh);
  }
```

The game works fine when I use the base model offered in the tutorial (the skull from this tutorial https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/mesh/mesh-from-obj ) But When I try to import my model from 3DS max, errors start popping out.
In particular, I receive different errors depending on the model on the addVerticesFromObj  function.

When I try to load the full model (composed of several objects), I receive the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'u')
    at t.exports (phaser.min.js:1:580548)
    at initialize.addVerticesFromObj (phaser.min.js:1:298100)
    at Scene1.create (Scene1.js:54:10)
    at initialize.create (phaser.min.js:1:491015)
    at initialize.loadComplete (phaser.min.js:1:490466)
    at o.emit (phaser.min.js:1:7809)
    at initialize.loadComplete (phaser.min.js:1:944358)
    at initialize.fileProcessComplete (phaser.min.js:1:944058)
    at initialize.onProcessComplete (phaser.min.js:1:21253)
    at initialize.onProcess (phaser.min.js:1:303819)
```

When I try to load the model of a single object, I receive the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')
    at t.exports (phaser.min.js:1:580422)
    at initialize.addVerticesFromObj (phaser.min.js:1:298100)
    at Scene1.create (Scene1.js:54:10)
    at initialize.create (phaser.min.js:1:491015)
    at initialize.loadComplete (phaser.min.js:1:490466)
    at o.emit (phaser.min.js:1:7809)
    at initialize.loadComplete (phaser.min.js:1:944358)
    at initialize.fileProcessComplete (phaser.min.js:1:944058)
    at initialize.onProcessComplete (phaser.min.js:1:21253)
    at initialize.onProcess (phaser.min.js:1:303819)
```

This happens only by changing the filename without modifying the rest of the code.
Could It be that there are special export parameters from 3DS max I need to set? Or is there another error in my code I cannot see?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the solution, but in the documentation it says: _Note: You should ensure your 3D package has triangulated the OBJ file prior to export._ may be this helps . Here the [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin.html#obj__anchor). I sadly don't have 3dMax so I can try this myself.

Comment: It is not 3DSMax, but in blender a default export didn't work, but when I deactivated all options except **triangulate faces** and **write materials** on export there is no error, and the object appears.